# What overcomes the DR granted by Fighter Armor Mastery?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, fighter, damage-reduction

> Armor Mastery (Ex):
>   At 19th level, a fighter gains Damage Reduction 5/— whenever he is wearing armor or using a shield.

What overcomes this Damage Reduction? Nothing?

playing Pathfinder

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nothing overcomes this Damage Reduction (besides things that completely ignore DR, like energy damage).  That's what the dash means.

[PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Damage-Reduction):

> The numerical part of a creature's damage reduction (or DR) is the amount of damage the creature ignores from normal attacks. Usually, a certain type of weapon can overcome this reduction (see Overcoming DR). This information is separated from the damage reduction number by a slash. For example, DR 5/magic means that a creature takes 5 less points of damage from all weapons that are not magic. If a dash follows the slash, then the damage reduction is effective against any attack that does not ignore damage reduction.

Comment: Now I'm trying to figure out why this had a downvote.

Comment: @TuggyNE I answered before the asker clarified the system they were playing - if I wasn't 100% sure it was Pathfinder, I'd have waited, but...  well, it's a system that uses the DR 5/- format where Fighters get Armor Mastery at level 19.  If that describes more than one system, I'll print and eat my answer with a little teriyaki sauce.